Precipitation of lead and zinc hydroxide
Excess of hydroxide forms complex with lead and zinc salts. If we add drop wise lead nitrate to a solution of sodium hydroxide the precipitates formed gets dissolved in excess of hydroxide. There will be a time when almost all the hydroxide would have reacted with lead forming the complex does addition of extra lead remains in the solution in ionic form or forms lead hydroxide precipitates taking hydroxide ions from the complex ?

Are you asking about the law of mass action?

No, I meant suppose I have a solution of lead hydroxide complex formed by excess of hydroxide that is soluble. If now we add soluble lead salt. Do they both the lead hydroxide complex and lead salt react or remain in the solution in ionic forms

Actually nothing will happen. Once the complex is formed, the solution is saturated with the complex leaving no free ions, thus an equilibrium is reached. So, even if you add more lead solution, nothing will happen. See complex ion equilibria: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Coordination_Chemistry/Complex_Ion_Equilibria/Complex-Ion_Equilibria

You precipitate the lead (or zinc) hydroxide. When you have an amphoteric hydroxide, the aqueous cation is essentially a weak acid and the hydroxo complex anion a weak base, and they neutralize each other to form the uncharged hydroxide. Which in amphoteric cases typically has low solubility.
Contrast this with a purely (and in general more strongly) basic hydroxide like magnesium hydroxide. In that case the neutral hydroxide itself is the base and, even if only sparingly soluble like magnesium hydroxide, requires a basic solution to be precipitated.

I didn't understand your answer I meant suppose I have a solution of lead hydroxide complex formed by excess of hydroxide that is soluble. If now we add soluble lead salt. Do they both the lead hydroxide complex and lead salt react or remain in the solution in ionic forms. Basically does soluble lead salt reacts with lead hydroxide complex to form precipitate of lead hydroxide solid
